# HTB traffic shaping per IP - ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu

I've tried my best before asking, but struggling.

I am running 10.04 ubuntu server and it has a fast-ish 8 drive Raid5 array, which is home to a number of samba share points.

This machine only gets used as a nearline samba file server.

Files are ingested to here and later consolidated onto another server on the network for realtime access, so I need to implement some traffic shaping.

My aim is to stop each individual client from using more than 200mbps of the gigabit pipe to the switch.

So far I've managed to do this with HTB, but I've hit a brick wall.

Using the commands below I am able to throttle traffic leaving the interface, but I want to carve individual 200mbit pipes per client, not limit the overall traffic for the interface to 200mbit.

```
sudo /sbin/tc qdisc del dev eth1 root

sudo /sbin/tc qdisc add dev eth1 root handle 1:0 htb default 10

sudo /sbin/tc class add dev eth1 parent 1:0 classid 1:10 htb rate 200mbps ceil 200mbps prio 0

sudo tc filter add dev eth1 parent 1:0 prio 0 protocol ip handle 10 fw flowid 1:10
```

Can anybody help with this?

I read that there is a way to do this with Shorewall per IP, but the kernel extension required is not present in the standard ubuntu kernel - and I can't find any information about patching to achieve what is required.

Im not a network admin, actually a film technician with too much on my plate.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you not need to mark the packets as a specific class ? as in iptables -s [ip] -j MARK --set-mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a 200Mbit limit for each IP, you have to add one class and filter with IP; I hope my memory is serving well :

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb  
for ((  i = 2 ;  i <= 10;  i++  ))
do
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:0 classid 1:$i htb rate 200Mbps 
tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip src 1.2.3.$i flowid 1:$i
done
```

Also you can use htb tool because it's more easy to understand.

Comment: Im almost there now, thanks to responses.

Receiving an "illegal match" response when I replace 1.2.3.$i with my IP range, leaving the .$i at the end.

Comment: try (notice the /32 after the 1.2.3.$i/32 ) : tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip src 1.2.3.$i/32 flowid 1:$i . If it is not working, maybe the "u32 match ip src" target is not supported by Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check the features supported in TC, if I run "sudo shorewall show capabilities" I receive a list of supported iptables/netfilter functions.

I suppose I can migrate to a different disto.

Comment: If still not working, replace 5th line with (from http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.qdisc.filters.html): tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 handle $i fw flowid 1:$i ; iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -i eth0 -s 1.2.3.$i -j MARK --set-mark $i

Comment: Perhaps best if I go back through the help at lartc.org :) ..I received the following.

Could not determine whether revision 1 is supported, assuming it is.
Could not determine whether revision 1 is supported, assuming it is.
Could not determine whether revision 2 is supported, assuming it is.
Bad argument `–'

Thanks for spending time helping me out :)